# how to use the facebook like button with ajax driven content and load dynamic content

Tags: ajax, facebook, button, facebook-like

I have searched the net for a solution but can't seem to get anywhere.

My page (php) is loading with one url (let's say www.mysite.com)
in the page several search options on music (albums) can be done and the tracks are shown. (without refreshing the page). the info comes from a database.
So the url stays the same.
In this search process the facebook meta tags (description, url, title) stay the same also because I never reload the page, I only load content into div's.

I would like to be able to 'like' the album, and backlink to it. So I have created the function to load the album by using the url: www.mysite.com?album=12345
I can show a popup with this url to share this. 
So, if you go to this url, the content is automatically loaded based on the url parameter.

And on this spot (where you can see the url with the parameter ?album=12345) I would like to show the 'like' button as well. (I generated the url, so I use this in the code:)

```
echo '<div style="overflow:visable" class="fb-like" data-href="http://mysite.com/?album='.$albumid.'" data-send="false" data-width="300" data-show-faces="false">?</div>';
```

it works so far... (after I added the parse code to enable the button)
However the like button takes the default meta tags description and title etc.
Not particular on this album or artist - so it's not unique.

Note: if I remove the meta[property=og:url] from the header I can make the button backlink to the right url with the ?album parameter. Otherwise it would go back to the default root of the site mysite.com (this does make the lint tool give an error on the missing meta)

I have tried to add into this same function something like:

```
$("meta[property=og\\:url]").attr("content", "http://mysite.com/?album=<?php echo $albumid; ?>");
$("meta[property=og\\:title]").attr("content", "<?php echo $artistname; ?>");
$("meta[property=og\\:description]").attr("content", "<?php echo $albumname; ?>");
```

I did this so the meta tags will be changed, just to let the like button show the right description etc. However this doesn't work.
I understand that facebook scrapes the page (I used the lint tool etc.) but I will never executes javascript, so the meta tags wil stay as default (when first loading the page)

What can I do to make a unique like button, with it's own description (albumname etc) without making a html page for each one of them (millions of albums in the database...)

I hope it makes sense.

I can't seem to figure this one out, help please :-)

---

Based on the comments below I used the following solution:

you should create the right fb meta tags when the url (with the params ?alb_id=12345) is opened.
That's enough for the like button to do its job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is fine, up to the point where you're setting the meta tags using jquery.
They should be set using PHP. As you can imagine the scraper won't execute the jquery, but if it's fed the already PHP-customized meta tags it will use them (as provided).

Just have the og:tags prepared server-side, depending on the albumId requested, and it should work. It might not work right away, I remember there used to be occasional caching issues with the scraper before.

In short, index.php?album=123 will send a different set of og:tags to the scraper than say index.php?album=321. Just set them up server-side.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $artistTitle; ?>"/>
```

Comment: right that makes sense.
But the meta tags are set in the <head> section.
And at that point there's no div yet where the function loads it's content into.
so basically it doing this order:
1. index.php
2. receiving url parameter
3. setting head
4. setting body
5. making divs
6. body onload= starting the function to load content into div according to url parameter.
-> so This function calls another php which loads content from the database and at that point I can set the meta tags (because untill then I don't know the album name etc.)
So How can I fill the head section with php there?

Comment: You can't really, if you're getting information only after loading additional content on user's end, then it's of no use, scraper won't execute any of the additional loading. You need to get that information when your head tag is created in your index.php file, you can probably reuse bits of the code you're using for the divs that you're loading. In short, request all needed info (based on your album in the url) when creating your head element and put it in there.

Comment: hmm ok, this is not going to work :-(
because you can enter a new album into the div at any time (and the meta tags are already there) without reloading the page.

I'm wondering what people with products etc. do when they load it into div with Ajax. You wouldn't be able to set like buttons also.

Comment: The scraper only goes to the page when the like button is clicked (not when it's loaded), so you can create albums whenever you like, as long as when the scraper goes to the page, it gets the right og tags. The like button doesn't have to link to your index.php page, it can link to a different page altogether (without any like buttons for example, which sole purpose is to serve og tags), just make sure it has the right og tags. It's a simple process - user clicks on the like button, scraper goes to liked page, scraper reads og:tags in the head tag.

Comment: wow Evident - you are really thinking with me now.
I appreciate that a lot!
I haven't thought of that.
The downside of that is, the users clicking on the 'liked' button on their facebook pages will be redirected to that link also.
So it should recognise whether it's the scraper or a browser visiting the page.

Comment: Not if you still use index.php, really, all you have to do is check if there is a album parameter in the URL, if there is one, connect to the database, get the info on the album, put in the tags in the head element, display appropriate content in the page. If there is no album in the URL use default tags, default content.

Comment: grrr it's driving me nuts.
I had a fine solution with: $.get('artist.php?type=rg_meta,'.$alb_id, function(data){ $(data).appendTo("head");)}
But that is javascript too and doesn't get executed by the scraper.
is there some php equivalent to $.get to parse the artist.php file (this will get the info from the db)

Comment: Thanks EvidentAgenda - your comments helped me to get it working and what seemed impossible for a moment.

Answer (score 0):

> What can I do to make a unique like button, with it's own description (albumname etc) without making a html page for each one of them (millions of albums in the database...)

You can’t, because Open Graph objects *are* URLs (resp. are *represented/identified* by their URL).

One URL == one Open Graph object.

But where’s the problem in having one URL for each album? Since it all works using parameters, it’s not like you have to create a page for each album URL manually …

Comment: well, each album does have its own url.
however when clicking on the like button the same description is always used. Because it gets it from the meta tags which are in the header...
That is because the whole lot is loaded into the index.php default page.

Comment: Of course you have to explicitly __set__ the URL you want to be liked for the like button. If no URL is set, _then_ it just takes the current document’s address as the one to be liked.